# Add an outside number to each element in an array

Tags: java, arraylist, jgrasp

I need to add an outside number to EVERY number in an ArrayList. I've looked for 2 days trying to find a similar answer and found nothing.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  list.add(12);
  list.add(45);
  list.add(23);
  list.add(47);
  list.add(13);

public static void modifyList(ArrayList<Integer> theList, int value)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++)
  {
    theList.add(theList[i],value);
  }
}
```

I've tried various combinations of the add feature for ArrayList but there is always a different error and i'm starting to go crazy

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you give an input/output example?

Comment: @HugoSousa It should be displayed as: LIST = 12, 45, 23, 47, 13; then with the modifyList method it should add any declared integer to each element in the array. If i used 1 it should change to: LIST = 13, 46, 23, 48, 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic will be as below :

```
for (int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++) {
            int oldValue = theList.get(i);
            int newValue = oldValue + value;
            theList.set(i, newValue);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the set method.

```
Arraylist.set(index,value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the i value from an arraylist works using the get method.

You have:

```
theList.add(theList[i], value);
```

It should probably be:

```
theList.add(theList.get(i));
```

If you want to change the i element in the list, then you can use the set method.

```
theList.set(i, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = theList.get(i) + your_addition;

theList.set(i, a);
```